# Determining whether a function is well-defined

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Okay, so I think I have this figured out. I have two functions that are proposed recursive definitions. from the set of non-negative integers to the set of integers.

$$f(0)=0,\quad f(1)=1,\quad f(n)=2f(n-1)\text{ for }n \geq 1.$$

I came up with the equation $2^{(2-n)/2}$

I put it's Not well-defined because the range starts with 1. And with 1 already defined when plugged into the equation it becomes zero.

$$f(0)=1,\quad f(1)=0,\quad f(n)=2f(n-2)$$

Not well defined because all odd n equal zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of this question is to realize a function is well defined if it satisfies the initial conditions for recursion. For example, take your first recursive function.

$$f(0)=0, f(1)=1, f(n) = 2f(n-1) \quad n \geq 1$$

Notice that if we plug in $1$

$$1= f(1) = 2 f( 1 - 1) = 2 f(0) = 2*0 = 0 \implies 1 = 0 ??? $$

Obviously this isn't well defined. For your second recursive function we have

$$ f(0)=1, f(1)=0, f(n)=2f(n-2)\quad n \geq 2$$

Here we see that:

$$f(2) = 2 f(0) =2*1 =2$$
$$f(3) = 2 f(1) =2*0 =0$$
$$f(4) = 2 f(2) =2*2 = 4$$
etc...
Which is easily summarized as

$$ f(n) = \begin{cases}
2^\frac{n}{2} & \text{ if $n$ is even} \\ 
0 & \text{ if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

As you can see, this function is well defined since everything makes sense.